# R Iterate dataset generation

Tags: r, loops, iteration, normal-distribution

I want to generate 21 random normal distribution `data.frames` with two variables (using `mvrnorm`), based on 21 parameters that are stored in `[1:21] num/chr` strings. Plus, each data.frame should contain two columns with strings that are identical for each of the 21 sets (That'll make sense once I `rbind` them together)

Let's say *AGQ.mu2.mat* stores means for the first variable (stddev = 1), *Std.mu2.mat* for the second (stddev = 20), and *ORIG* and *ID* store the two strings (I replaced the data with some LotR names), and let *corr* be = .30 and *n* always 300:

```
r<-0.30
ORIG<-c("Ang","Ang","Ang","DGu","DGu","DGu", "Har", 
        "Har", "Har", "Isg", "Isg", "Isg", "Mor", "Mor", 
        "Mor", "MMo", "MMo", "MMo", "Rhu", "Rhu", "Rhu")
ID<-c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c",
         "a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c")
AGQ.mu2.mat <- c(-1.06, -1.27, -1.97, -3.27, -3.32, -2.32, -1.05, -0.36, -1.85, -2.30, -2.49, -2.90, -0.80, -0.62, -0.56,  1.22,  1.62,  0.44, -1.43, -1.08, -2.34)
Std.mu2.mat <- c(107, 100, 102, 124, 118, 120, 147, 152, 141, 154, 160, 155, 125, 123, 116, 103, 106, 107, 123, 126, 117)
```

I want to iterate

```
dt<-data.frame(mvrnorm(n=300, mu=c(AGQ.mu2.mat[1],Std.mu2.mat[1]),
                       Sigma=matrix(c(1, r*20, r*20, (20^2)),
                                  nrow=2), empirical=TRUE))
dt<-rename(dt, "AGQ" = "X1","Std" = "X2")
dt$Herkunft<-ORIG[1]
dt$Bat_ID<-ID[1]
```

over all 21 entries of the parameter vectors, resulting in 21 uniquely named data frames.

I've tried

```
for (i in 1:21)
  {
dt<-data.frame(mvrnorm(n=300, mu=c(AGQ.mu2.mat[i],Std.mu2.mat[i]),
                       Sigma=matrix(c(1, r*20, r*20, (20^2)),
                                  nrow=2), empirical=TRUE))
dt<-rename(dt, "AGQ" = "X1","Std" = "X2")
dt$Herkunft<-ORIG[i]
dt$Bat_ID<-ID[i]
}
```

and

```
dt<-data.frame(mvrnorm(n=300, mu=c(rep(AGQ.mu2.mat,each=1),rep(Std.mu2.mat, each=1)),
                       Sigma=matrix(c(1, r*20, r*20, (20^2)),
                                    nrow=2), empirical=TRUE))
dt<-rename(dt, "Aggr" = "X1","Std" = "X2")
dt$Herkunft<-rep(ORIG,each=1)
dt$Bat_ID<-rep(ID,each=1)
```

to no avail; and even then, this would generate the same dataset over and over without creating uniquely named new ones.

I'd really appreciate any help or approaches on how to iterate this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: added AGQ.mu2.mat and Std.mu2.mat.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use some way to gather the results. I choose to use `list` which is appended. Other solution might be to use `rbind`. You have to shape your matrix with nrow/ncol arguments.

```r
library(MASS)

r<-0.30
ORIG<-c("Ang","Ang","Ang","DGu","DGu","DGu", "Har", 
        "Har", "Har", "Isg", "Isg", "Isg", "Mor", "Mor", 
        "Mor", "MMo", "MMo", "MMo", "Rhu", "Rhu", "Rhu")
ID<-c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c",
         "a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c")

AGQ.mu2.mat <- 1:21
Std.mu2.mat <- 1:21

results <- list()

for (i in 1:21) {
dt<-data.frame(mvrnorm(n=300, mu=c(AGQ.mu2.mat[i],Std.mu2.mat[i]),
                       Sigma=matrix(c(1, r*20, r*20, (20^2)), nrow = 2), empirical=TRUE))
colnames(dt) <- c("AGQ","Std")
dt$Herkunft<-ORIG[i]
dt$Bat_ID<-ID[i]

results[[i]] <- dt
}
```

join all results

```r
do.call(rbind, results)
```

validation:

```r
> cor(results[[1]][,1:2]);apply(results[[1]][,1:2], 2, mean);apply(results[[1]][,1:2], 2, sd)
    AGQ Std
AGQ 1.0 0.3
Std 0.3 1.0
AGQ Std 
  1   1 
AGQ Std 
  1  20
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution using `dplyr` and `purrr` may help...

```r
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

r <-0.30

ORIG<-c("Ang","Ang","Ang","DGu","DGu","DGu", "Har", 
        "Har", "Har", "Isg", "Isg", "Isg", "Mor", "Mor", 
        "Mor", "MMo", "MMo", "MMo", "Rhu", "Rhu", "Rhu")

ID<-c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c",
      "a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c")

AGQ.mu2.mat <- c(-1.06, -1.27, -1.97, -3.27, -3.32, -2.32, -1.05, -0.36, -1.85, -2.30, -2.49, -2.90, -0.80, -0.62, -0.56,  1.22,  1.62,  0.44, -1.43, -1.08, -2.34)
Std.mu2.mat <- c(107, 100, 102, 124, 118, 120, 147, 152, 141, 154, 160, 155, 125, 123, 116, 103, 106, 107, 123, 126, 117)

listofdf <- purrr::map2(AGQ.mu2.mat, 
            Std.mu2.mat,
            ~ data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n = 300, 
                                       mu=c(.x, .y),
                                       Sigma = matrix(c(1, r*20, r*20, (20^2)), nrow=2), 
                                       empirical=TRUE))
) %>% 
   purrr::map2(ORIG, ~ mutate(.x, Herkunft = .y)) %>%
   purrr::map2(ID, ~ mutate(.x, Bat_ID = .y))

head(listofdf[[4]])
#>          X1         X2 Herkunft Bat_ID
#> 1 0.4329040  17.616240      DGu      a
#> 2 2.6589457  -9.385099      DGu      a
#> 3 2.3626722   9.815020      DGu      a
#> 4 1.8998816 -24.551505      DGu      a
#> 5 0.2506713   0.792565      DGu      a
#> 6 3.4961960   8.112878      DGu      a


### since you mentioned binding them all together
onebigdf <- bind_rows(listofdf)
```

Comment: How stupid of me. I edited the question to add them. Thank you for your solution!

Comment: I edited to make it valid code and my solution still works